# C++ Include two classes that derive from the same base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, header

I have a Base class `Base`.
Two classes that derive from it: `DerivedA` and `DerivedB`. In headers of both classes I included `Base.h`.
Then, in my `source.cpp` where I define my `main`, if I ONLY include `DerivedA.h`, it works fine. If I ONLY include `DerivedB.h` it also works fine. The problem is that I can't include BOTH.
Whenever I include both, the compiler generate a bunch of errors like

- left of '.debit' must have class/struct/union
- 'getBalance' : is not a member of 'CheckingAccount'

I guess the problem is that when I include both header, the `Base.h` is included twice. How should I include these headers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the problem is just the header file and not a case of the [deadly diamond of death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadly_Diamond_of_Death#The_diamond_problem), you could just use `#pragma once` in your header file and that will ensure it's only ever linked once during the build process.

Alternatively, you could wrap your header file in something like this:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_

// The content of the header file goes here...

#endif
```

By using pre-processor `#ifXXXX` statements, you can tell the compiler to only include the file if a macro is not already pre-defined.

Comment: *Note:* `#pragma once` is supported by a lot of compilers, but it's not standard C++. The alternative version ("include guards") works with every C++ compiler.

Comment: Do you mean "*you can tell the compiler to only include the file if a macro is **not** already pre-defined*"?

Comment: Also note: #pragma once is much, much faster than include guards on large projects

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do you think of another solution which I just came up: Putting definitions of both DerivedA.h and DerivedB.h into one file and refer to it from the cpp file of both classes?

Comment: Can't really say one is definitively better. In general more separation is better, but there are plenty of examples to the contrary as well. I will say though that it's typically easier to merge two separate things than it is to separate one merged thing into two. If you have it separated, just keep it that way until you find compelling reason to change it.

Comment: @octref Easier solution than that would be to say `#include "Base.h" #include "DerivedA.h" #include "DerivedB.h"` in your **.cpp** file, instead of including it in those headers. It's not ideal but better than having to merge the files. This is the fundamental idea behind precompiled headers.

Answer (score -1):

When you are inheriting from two classes which are from the same base, you should try to use the keyword "virtual" when doing the inheritance. It helps you to solve the confusion in the virtual table I believe. Look up virtual inheritance for examples.

Comment: I didn't even mention "virtual" in my question and I know how to use this keyword.

Comment: Isn't that the way to solve multiple inheritance issue? Maybe I read it wrong as you are not in the diamond inheritance case.

Comment: @JohnYang - it is the way to solve **some** multiple inheritance issues. And, yes, it probably won't solve anything here, although that's just speculation, since the question contains **no code**.